# ZSH on 10.9: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I am new to ZSH and have been using oh-my-zsh to rum ZSH on OSX 10.9.  I've been trying to take an advantage of a history plugin but I get this, "widgets can only be called when ZLE is active." when invoke any of history related commands.  I've looked for a way to circumvent this but have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: Run `zmodload` in a shell and check whether `zsh/zle` is listed. If it's not, you'll need to load it before the `oh-my-zsh` plugin. You can do this in `~/.zshrc` *before* the `source oh-my-zsh` line: `zmodload zsh/zle`.

Comment: A result of zmodload shows that zle is loaded but I am still getting the same error, "widgets can only be called when ZLE is active." how  else can I activate ale ?

Answer (score 4):

Its a [bug](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3620#issuecomment-75435240) in `oh-my-zsh`. To fix it put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
TRAPWINCH() {
  zle && { zle reset-prompt; zle -R }
}
```

Explanation:

> With no options and no arguments, only the return status will be set.
>   It is zero if ZLE is currently active and widgets could be invoked
>   using this builtin command and non-zero otherwise. Note that even if
>   non-zero status is returned, zle may still be active as part of the
>   completion system; this does not allow direct calls to ZLE widgets.

Comment: I added your code to my .zshrc file, sourced it, but I am still having an error message saying "zle: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active". zmodload shows that zle is loaded.